# IPv6 not establishing connection for iwlwifi

Tags: networking, wifi, ipv6, iwlwifi

I receive IPv6 from the router, DNS and gateway seems to be correct, other machines in the same network are able to establish connection via IPv6.

I tested using a USB adapter and it worked, which indicates that may be a driver issue. Other machines that use the same kernel driver are working in this network, which makes me confused.

I also tested using Windows OS and it worked, what indicates that it's not a hardware issue.

I'm lacking knowledge to trace what is wrong here...

**Subject machine**

```
# uname -r
5.13.0-51-generic

# ip a
3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 60:dd:XX:XX:XX:XX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname wlp41s0
    inet 192.168.0.14/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlo1
       valid_lft 604481sec preferred_lft 604481sec
    inet6 2a02:8109:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:d5ce/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 604483sec preferred_lft 604483sec
    inet6 2a02:8109:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:bcb2/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 299sec preferred_lft 299sec
    inet6 fe80::XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:c83e/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

# ip -6 r
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2a02:8109:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:d5ce dev wlo1 proto kernel metric 600 pref medium
2a02:8109:XXXX:XXXX::/64 dev wlo1 proto ra metric 600 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev wlo1 proto kernel metric 600 pref medium
default via fe80::XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:2414 dev wlo1 proto ra metric 600 pref medium

# resolvectl status
...
Link 3 (wlo1)
      Current Scopes: DNS                                  
DefaultRoute setting: yes                                  
       LLMNR setting: yes                                  
MulticastDNS setting: no                                   
  DNSOverTLS setting: no                                   
      DNSSEC setting: no                                   
    DNSSEC supported: no                                   
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.0.1                          
         DNS Servers: 192.168.0.1                          
                      2a02:8109:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:2414
          DNS Domain: ~.                                   

# lspci -kvnn | sed '/Network/,/^$/!d'
29:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz [8086:2725] (rev 1a)
        DeviceName: RTL8125B Giga LAN
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz [8086:0024]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 35
        Memory at fcd00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi

# sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:29:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 1a
       serial: 60:dd:XX:XX:XX:XX
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.13.0-51-generic firmware=63.c04f3485.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-63.uc ip=192.168.0.14 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:35 memory:fcd00000-fcd03fff
...

# dmesg | grep iwl
[    7.064318] iwlwifi 0000:29:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    7.071159] iwlwifi 0000:29:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    7.071172] iwlwifi 0000:29:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 0.0.2.25
[    7.071386] iwlwifi 0000:29:00.0: loaded firmware version 63.c04f3485.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-63.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    7.196363] iwlwifi 0000:29:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
[    7.349032] iwlwifi 0000:29:00.0: loaded PNVM version 0xd35929d8
[    7.427647] iwlwifi 0000:29:00.0: base HW address: 60:dd:XX:XX:XX:XX
[    7.444665] iwlwifi 0000:29:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[    9.625992] Modules linked in: amd64_edac(-) intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_hda_codec_realtek iwlmvm snd_hda_codec_generic amdgpu(+) ledtrig_audio mac80211 snd_hda_codec_hdmi iommu_v2 libarc4 gpu_sched snd_hda_intel drm_ttm_helper snd_intel_dspcfg ttm snd_intel_sdw_acpi uvcvideo snd_hda_codec edac_mce_amd snd_usb_audio drm_kms_helper videobuf2_vmalloc snd_hda_core btusb snd_usbmidi_lib videobuf2_memops iwlwifi cec btrtl videobuf2_v4l2 snd_hwdep rc_core btbcm kvm_amd snd_seq_midi videobuf2_common i2c_algo_bit ax88179_178a btintel snd_seq_midi_event fb_sys_fops kvm usbnet snd_rawmidi videodev syscopyarea sysfillrect crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel nls_iso8859_1 snd_pcm mc mii bluetooth sysimgblt joydev input_leds snd_seq cfg80211 aesni_intel crypto_simd ecdh_generic cryptd ecc snd_seq_device rapl snd_timer snd soundcore ccp efi_pstore wmi_bmof k10temp mac_hid sch_fq_codel drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid nvme r8169 ahci xhci_pci gpio_amdpt crc32_pclmul
[    9.627700] Modules linked in: amd64_edac(-) intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_hda_codec_realtek iwlmvm snd_hda_codec_generic amdgpu(+) ledtrig_audio mac80211 snd_hda_codec_hdmi iommu_v2 libarc4 gpu_sched snd_hda_intel drm_ttm_helper snd_intel_dspcfg ttm snd_intel_sdw_acpi uvcvideo snd_hda_codec edac_mce_amd snd_usb_audio drm_kms_helper videobuf2_vmalloc snd_hda_core btusb snd_usbmidi_lib videobuf2_memops iwlwifi cec btrtl videobuf2_v4l2 snd_hwdep rc_core btbcm kvm_amd snd_seq_midi videobuf2_common i2c_algo_bit ax88179_178a btintel snd_seq_midi_event fb_sys_fops kvm usbnet snd_rawmidi videodev syscopyarea sysfillrect crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel nls_iso8859_1 snd_pcm mc mii bluetooth sysimgblt joydev input_leds snd_seq cfg80211 aesni_intel crypto_simd ecdh_generic cryptd ecc snd_seq_device rapl snd_timer snd soundcore ccp efi_pstore wmi_bmof k10temp mac_hid sch_fq_codel drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid nvme r8169 ahci xhci_pci gpio_amdpt crc32_pclmul
[   14.527808] iwlwifi 0000:29:00.0: Got NSS = 4 - trimming to 2
...

# ping6 -c5 ipv6.google.com
PING ipv6.google.com(ham11s01-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4005:800::200e)) 56 data bytes

--- ipv6.google.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4084ms

# traceroute6 ipv6.google.com
traceroute to ipv6.google.com (2a00:1450:4005:802::200e), 30 hops max, 80 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
...

# nc -vzw5 ipv6.google.com 443
nc: connect to ipv6.google.com port 443 (tcp) timed out: Operation now in progress
```

**Subject machine with USB adapter**

```
# ip a
3: wlo1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 60:dd:XX:XX:XX:XX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname wlp41s0
7: wlx00e61804d62d: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e6:XX:XX:XX:XX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.239/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlx00e61804d62d
       valid_lft 604627sec preferred_lft 604627sec
    inet6 2a02:8109:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:c624/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 604631sec preferred_lft 604631sec
    inet6 2a02:8109:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:b69d/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 300sec preferred_lft 300sec
    inet6 2a02:8109:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:84e5/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 300sec preferred_lft 300sec
    inet6 fe80::XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:9241/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

# ip -6 r
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2a02:8109:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:c624 dev wlx00e61804d62d proto kernel metric 600 pref medium
2a02:8109:XXXX:XXXX::/64 dev wlx00e61804d62d proto ra metric 600 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev wlx00e61804d62d proto kernel metric 600 pref medium
default via fe80::XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:2414 dev wlx00e61804d62d proto ra metric 600 pref medium

# resolvectl status
....
Link 7 (wlx00e61804d62d)
      Current Scopes: DNS                                  
DefaultRoute setting: yes                                  
       LLMNR setting: yes                                  
MulticastDNS setting: no                                   
  DNSOverTLS setting: no                                   
      DNSSEC setting: no                                   
    DNSSEC supported: no                                   
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.0.1                          
         DNS Servers: 192.168.0.1                          
                      2a02:8109:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:2414

# lsusb -d 148f:7601 -v
Bus 003 Device 017: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.01
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x148f Ralink Technology, Corp.
  idProduct          0x7601 MT7601U Wireless Adapter
  bcdDevice            0.00
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 3 
  bNumConfigurations      1
...

# sudo lshw -C network
...
*-network:1
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@3:2.3
       logical name: wlx00e61804d62d
       serial: 00:e6:XX:XX:XX:XX
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt7601u driverversion=5.13.0-51-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.239 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11

# ping6 -c5 ipv6.google.com
PING ipv6.google.com(ham11s01-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4005:800::200e)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from ham11s01-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4005:800::200e): icmp_seq=1 ttl=115 time=14.6 ms
64 bytes from ham11s01-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4005:800::200e): icmp_seq=2 ttl=115 time=14.4 ms
64 bytes from ham11s01-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4005:800::200e): icmp_seq=3 ttl=115 time=16.8 ms
64 bytes from ham11s01-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4005:800::200e): icmp_seq=4 ttl=115 time=13.1 ms
64 bytes from ham11s01-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4005:800::200e): icmp_seq=5 ttl=115 time=16.4 ms

--- ipv6.google.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4007ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 13.099/15.049/16.779/1.350 ms

# traceroute6 ipv6.google.com
traceroute to ipv6.google.com (2a00:1450:4005:802::200e), 30 hops max, 80 byte packets
 1  2a02:8109:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:2414 (2a02:8109:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:2414)  18.089 ms  19.697 ms  19.952 ms
 2  2a02:8109:XXXX:XXXX::1 (2a02:8109:XXXX:XXXX::1)  38.359 ms  38.682 ms  39.005 ms
 3  2a02:8100:XXXX:XXXX::XXXX:1091 (2a02:8100:XXXX:XXXX::XXXX:1091)  32.614 ms  33.349 ms  36.238 ms
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  2001:4860:1:1::1d4 (2001:4860:1:1::1d4)  18.930 ms 2001:4860:1:1::4d6 (2001:4860:1:1::4d6)  17.899 ms  18.263 ms
 9  2a00:1450:8160::1 (2a00:1450:8160::1)  18.587 ms  25.496 ms 2a00:1450:80b0::1 (2a00:1450:80b0::1)  34.272 ms
10  2001:4860:0:1::1b5e (2001:4860:0:1::1b5e)  30.911 ms 2001:4860:0:1::21a2 (2001:4860:0:1::21a2)  27.463 ms ham02s21-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4005:802::200e)  21.652 ms

# nc -vzw5 ipv6.google.com 443
Connection to ipv6.google.com 443 port [tcp/https] succeeded!
```

**Subject machine with Windows OS**

In that case I used only [ipv6-test.com](https://ipv6-test.com)!

[image]

**Other machine with iwlwifi driver in same network**

```
# uname -r
5.13.0-51-generic

# ip a
2: wlp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f4:a4:XX:XX:XX:XX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.229/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp1s0
       valid_lft 600850sec preferred_lft 600850sec
    inet6 2a02:8109:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:b615/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 600854sec preferred_lft 600854sec
    inet6 2a02:8109:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:54a7/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 299sec preferred_lft 299sec
    inet6 fe80::XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:2e7c/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

# ip -6 r
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2a02:8109:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:b615 dev wlp1s0 proto kernel metric 600 pref medium
2a02:8109:XXXX:XXXX::/64 dev wlp1s0 proto ra metric 600 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev wlp1s0 proto kernel metric 600 pref medium
default via fe80::XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:2414 dev wlp1s0 proto ra metric 600 pref medium

# resolvectl status
...
Link 2 (wlp1s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS                                  
DefaultRoute setting: yes                                  
       LLMNR setting: yes                                  
MulticastDNS setting: no                                   
  DNSOverTLS setting: no                                   
      DNSSEC setting: no                                   
    DNSSEC supported: no                                   
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.0.1                          
         DNS Servers: 192.168.0.1                          
                      2a02:8109:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:2414
          DNS Domain: ~.

# lspci -kvnn | sed '/Network/,/^$/!d'
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz [8086:2725] (rev 1a)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz [8086:0024]
        Physical Slot: 0
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 63
        Memory at fcf00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi

# sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 1a
       serial: f4:a4:XX:XX:XX:XX
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.13.0-51-generic firmware=63.c04f3485.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-63.uc ip=192.168.0.229 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:63 memory:fcf00000-fcf03fff

# dmesg | fgrep iwl
[    4.875448] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.894565] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    4.894596] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 0.0.2.25
[    4.895073] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 63.c04f3485.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-63.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.039753] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
[    5.196189] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded PNVM version 0xd35929d8
[    5.277747] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: base HW address: f4:a4:XX:XX:XX:XX
[    5.299368] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
[    9.117613] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Got NSS = 4 - trimming to 2

# ping6 -c5 ipv6.google.com
PING ipv6.google.com(ham02s21-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4005:802::200e)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from ham02s21-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4005:802::200e): icmp_seq=1 ttl=115 time=20.0 ms
64 bytes from ham02s21-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4005:802::200e): icmp_seq=2 ttl=115 time=16.2 ms
64 bytes from ham02s21-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4005:802::200e): icmp_seq=3 ttl=115 time=16.6 ms
64 bytes from ham02s21-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4005:802::200e): icmp_seq=4 ttl=115 time=14.5 ms
64 bytes from ham02s21-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4005:802::200e): icmp_seq=5 ttl=115 time=14.5 ms

--- ipv6.google.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4008ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 14.477/16.351/19.969/1.998 ms

# traceroute6 ipv6.google.com
traceroute to ipv6.google.com (2a00:1450:4005:802::200e), 30 hops max, 80 byte packets
 1  2a02:8109:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:2414 (2a02:8109:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:2414)  3.362 ms  3.873 ms  4.390 ms
 2  2a02:8109:XXXX:XXXX::1 (2a02:8109:XXXX:XXXX::1)  13.531 ms  18.277 ms  18.404 ms
 3  2a02:8100:XXXX:XXXX::XXXX:1091 (2a02:8100:XXXX:XXXX::XXXX:1091)  17.607 ms  17.688 ms  17.803 ms
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  2001:4860:1:1::4d6 (2001:4860:1:1::4d6)  21.511 ms  21.498 ms  21.884 ms
 9  2a00:1450:8160::1 (2a00:1450:8160::1)  21.041 ms * *
10  ham02s21-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4005:802::200e)  18.835 ms  18.479 ms *

# nc -vzw5 ipv6.google.com 443
Connection to ipv6.google.com 443 port [tcp/https] succeeded!
```

What more can I do?

Comment: After I rebooted the router it started working, I wonder if it was a router bug or maybe related to Windows dual-boot changing a hardware state that bugs Linux, I'll check it soon...

Comment: Apparently it's not related to Windows. It's still a mystery what happened, given such conditions. Since it isn't happening anymore I'll leave it here if someone has the same problem or if it happens again with me in the future, so I can investigate further.